# mongo-cxx-driver -New C++11 driver - How to create Document from binary data

Tags: c++, mongodb, c++11

for a project I need a c++ implementation for bson. 
According to the BSON Specs there are serveral bson c++ implementations.
I already tried each of them.
[Bson-cpp](https://github.com/jbenet/bson-cpp) isnt supported anymore.
[Bson-cxx](https://github.com/dwight/bson-cxx) wont even compile on my debian stretch.

So I tried the official mongodb-cxx-driver. 
But i want to use the current master-branch of the driver which contains the new c++11 driver because it uses cmake as build system. I already managed to create a bson document and convert it to a binary array. My problem at the moment is that I don't get how to create a bson document from an array of binary data even after digging through their code for two hours.

Is this functionality even implemented at the moment ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The C++11 driver from MongoDB offers a few interfaces for BSON writing and one interface for reading.

If what you want to do is read some already serialized bson:

```
bsoncxx::document::view view(data, length); // make a view
view["key"]; // fetch a key
view.find("key"); // map style iterator
for (auto x : view) {} // C++11 for loop

// or to load an array
bsoncxx::array::view view(data, length);
view[N];
// etc...
```

If you'd like to write some bson:

For a streaming api:

```
using namespace bsoncxx::builder::stream;
// Use builder::stream::array for array building
document b;

// Makes { "key" : "value", "subdoc" : { "sub key a" : 1 } }
b << "key" << "value" << "subdoc" <<
  << open_document << "sub key a" << 1 << close_document;

// to concatenate
b << concatenate(view);

// to use a non-deducible type like a sub doc
b << "key" << bsoncxx::types::b_document{view}

b.view() // gets a view

// take ownership of the bson bytes in a move only value type
bsoncxx::document::value v = b.extract()
```

For a simple key value api:

```
using namespace bsoncxx::builder::basic;

// Use builder::basic::array for array building
document b;

b.append(
    kvp("key", "value"),
    // Use sub_array for sub arrays
    kvp("subdoc", [](sub_document sd) {
        sd.append(kvp("sub key a", 1));
    })
);
```

That core api you found is certainly functional, but it's meant to provide a low level machine for BSON appending over a reallocing buffer, rather than an easy to use client interface. Prefer the builder::basic or builder::stream apis if you'd like some template magic to make construction more declarative.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Yesterday I also found the solution you mentioned. I think that is be the best way to do this.

Comment: There is now more information about the various BSON types offered in the C++11 driver [on this wiki page](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-cxx-driver/wiki/Handling-BSON-in-the-new-driver).

Answer (score 1):

After some more digging in their code I found the answer:

You can use:

```
bsoncxx::document::view(uint8_t* data, size_t length)
```

in order to create new view

Then you can use

```
bsoncxx::builder::core(bool isArray)
```

to create a new core
.On this core you can call

```
core.concatenate(view)
```

to insert the view into the new core.
Afterwards you can create new sub_document with:

```
bsoncxx::builder::basic:sub_document(core* c)
```

sub_document should provide all methods needed to extract the fields from the bson message.